# Login to website via Java?

Tags: java, javascript, http

I'm trying to make a program using java to access this [website](http://odus1.kau.edu.sa/students/) by inserting the username and the password and then get some data from the account when I log in. I search a lot through google and tried some [code](http://www.1your.com/drupal/LoginToWebsiteByHTTPPOSTCodeListing) but I had no much luck to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, just got this message `Successfully made the HTPP POST` and then `Recevied response is:` followed by the content of the page

Comment: Show us the code you are using right now.

Comment: I used this: http://www.1your.com/drupal/LoginToWebsiteByHTTPPOSTCodeListing

Comment: Logging into a University website programmatically is probably against their policies.

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. You're saying you get a response back, so what are you asking for help with?

Comment: the response is taken from the main page not the account page so the logging fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using is old tech; [Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) is a much simpler, more robust option and has tons of examples and documentation online. If you're not averse to Ruby, I'd throw [Watir](http://watir.com/) into the mix; or if you don't actually need code, and want just a simple record-playback automation, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking the understanding of the language I cannot give you concrete advice.

However the way to go is to check the form on the web page. Then you can send a post request to the site defined there.

As post body you send the parameters of the form like they would appear as URL parameters.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    String payload = "password=test&user=test" // password and user must be replaced with the names of the form fields and test with password and username respectively
    HttpURLConnection configConnection = new URL(formTarget).openConnection();
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("| Request ");
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("| URL: " + configConnection.getURL());
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("| Payload ");
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(payload);
    configConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    configConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    configConnection.getOutputStream().write(payload.getBytes());
    InputStream xmlInputStream = configConnection.getInputStream();

    int _byte = -1;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bios = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((_byte = xmlInputStream.read()) > -1) {
        bios.write(_byte);
    }
    final byte[] responseBytes = bios.toByteArray();
    String responseString = new String(responseBytes);
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("| Response ");
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("| Code: " + configConnection.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(responseString);
    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------");
```

To better parse the output you can use the [tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) library to transform it into proper xhtml.

Comment: there's no such method: `write(String)`

Comment: configConnection.getOutputStream().write(payload.getBytes()); // forgot to change this from my example

Comment: what about `isCompressed()` ?

Comment: Corrected remnants of the more complicated client library the example comes from.